# Verifying Amazon SNS signatures in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, amazon-sns

I have an ASP.NET endpoint where I receive Amazon SNS messages. I want to verify the signatures I receive along with those messages and have followed the guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html trying to match the Java code in C#. Here's what I have so far (I'm only interested in validating notifications, not subscription confirmations):

```
private X509Certificate2 cert;        

// cert is from constructor...

private bool IsValidMessageSignature(AmazonMessage msg)
{
    // Verify the signature
    var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
    var msgBytes = GetMessageBytes(msg);
    var signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(msg.Signature);
    return rsa.VerifyData(msgBytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signedBytes);
}

private byte[] GetMessageBytes(AmazonMessage msg)
{
    // Construct message string
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Message");
    sb.AppendLine(msg.Message);
    sb.AppendLine("MessageId");
    sb.AppendLine(msg.MessageId);
    if (msg.Subject != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Subject");
        sb.AppendLine(msg.Subject);
    }
    sb.AppendLine("Timestamp");
    sb.AppendLine(msg.Timestamp);
    sb.AppendLine("TopicArn");
    sb.AppendLine(msg.TopicArn);
    sb.AppendLine("Type");
    sb.AppendLine(msg.Type);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
}
```

The `rsa.VerifyData()` step returns false. I have built the example in Java as well, and here it works fine with the same message I'm trying to validate, and the same certificate that I'm using for C#.

Here's where the two programs differ as far as I can see. The C# `GetMessageBytes` byte-array returns 637 bytes, while the Java equivalent `getMessageBytesToSign` returns 627 bytes. Unfortunately I cannot post the message contents here for security reasons. My Java setup uses the windows-1252 charset by default, but even if I change the C# encoding to that the byte-array is still 637 in size. I'm not that experienced with encodings and the differences between C# and Java so I don't know if it's of any importance though.

Any ideas as to how my C# should be changed?

Comment: A wild guess, but perhaps the Java code uses \n for newlines and C# uses \r\n?

Comment: I've checked and they both use \r\n.

Comment: I checked the java code you linked to and it is just using \n ntoskrnl is correct.  ex: stringToSign = "Message\n";

Comment: What are the types of `msg.MessageId`, `msg.Timestamp` etc.? A time can be formatted as a string in many different ways. Same with a `Guid`, for example. But the difference of 10 bytes could match the fact that you have 10 `AppendLine`, so are you absolutely sure the `\r\n` is correct (@ntoskrnl's comment)?

Comment: You can check if `sb.ToString().Any(ch => ch > sbyte.MaxValue)`. If that is the case, UTF-8 should give more bytes than Windows-1252. If it is not the case, everything is ASCII, but you should still consider using `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(sb.ToString())`.

Comment: Also consider inspecting `string.Join(",", msgBytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))` directly to see what those 637 bytes are. Where is the difference from the 627 bytes in the Java code? You could even use a diff tool on the two strings or hex data.

Comment: ntoskrnl is right, my C# code produces \r\n while the Java code uses \n. This fixed my issue. @ntoskrnl You should post an answer if you wan't the bounty.

Comment: The example code at Amazon is somewhat poor because it uses the system-dependent default charset. It's Windows-1252 only on certain language versions of Windows. Other languages use other charsets, as do other platforms. In this case it doesn't matter if everything is ASCII, but in general you should always explicitly specify UTF-8 unless you have a special reason to use another charset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java code ends lines with `\n`. The C# version (`StringBuilder.AppendLine()`) uses `\r\n`.

Comment: I guess he could make an extension `public static StringBuilder AppendUnixLine(this StringBuilder self, string value) { return self.Append(value).Append("\n"); }`

Comment: `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` and similar methods append `Environment.NewLine` which (these days) is defined as `\r\n` for non-Unix platforms and `\n` for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 10):

```
Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Util.Message.ParseMessage(SNS_MESSAGE).IsMessageSignatureValid()
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService is totally your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me this way:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("Message\n");
sb.Append(notificationWrapper.Message).Append("\n");
sb.Append("MessageId\n");
sb.Append(notificationWrapper.MessageId).Append("\n");

if (notificationWrapper.Subject != null)
{
    sb.Append("Subject\n");
    sb.Append(notificationWrapper.Subject).Append("\n");
}

sb.Append("Timestamp\n");
sb.Append(notificationWrapper.Timestamp).Append("\n");
sb.Append("TopicArn\n");
sb.Append(notificationWrapper.TopicArn).Append("\n");
sb.Append("Type\n");
sb.Append(notificationWrapper.Type).Append("\n");

return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```